# Scarpa Manta - what size

Tags: boots

I've found a great deal on the old Scarpa Manta, but I'm not sure what size I'd be.

I have a pair of size 46 Scarpa SL3 boots (which use the BX last), so does it follow that I'd be 46 in the Manta, which seems to be the only boot to use the DL last?

Unfortunately the boot doesn't seem to be available anywhere locally to try on.

Comment: Hey Jonathan welcome to The Great Outdoors! This type of question is not exactly meant for this site, so you're not going to have much luck here. It's too localized to a specific brand and model and could be considered a shopping question. If you haven't already done so, please check out [this page about what types of questions to avoid](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and conversely [this page about how to ask good questions](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You **MUST NOT** buy hiking boots without trying them on. Period.

You want to hike in them - yet there are thousands of different foot forms and accordingly a lot of different boot cuts, differing in a lot more than only the length (which the size describes). There are wide and narrow boots, some with a high bumb under your instep and some with little and so on. There is no way of telling, if they fit for you or not if you don´t **TRY THEM ON!**

That said, the first link I found on google has a review that says them to be smaller and suggest ordering half a size bigger. Of course, you have to take into account how your old boots were - if you already bought them half a size bigger than normal (not unlikely if from the same company) then you probably don´t need to add to the size. However, only way telling is to **TRY THEM ON**!